# How can I learn sequence-to-sequence imputation model (SSIM and dual SSIM)?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, missing-data, data-imputation, recurrent-neural-network

I have read papers that have used this model for the imputation method.
Link: https://ivivan.com/papers/IOTJ2019.pdf
I want to read more and be able to use these models for the imputation of my own datasets. Can someone provide relevant documentation?